# How to pass maven-surefire-plugin params via command line

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin

According to the following [page](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) it is possible to specify custom listeners for the TestNG in the following way:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>
                            com.mycompany.MyResultListener,com.mycompany.MyAnnotationTransformer,com.mycompany.MyMethodInterceptor
                        </value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

My question is how can I do the same (to provide custom listeners) but via command line?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a property say tCustomListener

```
<properties>
  <tCustomListener>intelligent_default_listener</value>
</properties>
```

and pass it to `<value>` with `${tCustomListener}`

Run with -DtCustomListener=yourvalues

Comment: That will not work, you cannot specify the xml tag as <ttCustomListener></value>. Also to which properties do you refer - the pom properties or the plugin ones?